# scanPeriod attribute is required by logback-classic for auto-reload to work

Tags: logback

Is this a bug in logback classic or am I missing something? [The documentation](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#autoScan) is pretty explicit about `scanPeriod` being an optional attribute:

> By default, the configuration file will be scanned for changes once
>   every minute.

However, given a `logback.xml` file like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="true" scan="true" >           
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n</pattern>
            <charset>utf8</charset>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="WARN">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

I get the following output from logback and scan does **not** work.

```
16:40:56,244 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
16:40:56,244 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
16:40:56,244 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [file:/home/jbochenski/acme/acme-func-test/conf/logback.xml]
16:40:56,323 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
16:40:56,325 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [CONSOLE]
16:40:56,331 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
16:40:56,354 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to WARN
16:40:56,355 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [CONSOLE] to Logger[ROOT]
16:40:56,355 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
16:40:56,356 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@146ba0ac - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
```

However if I just change the configuration to add `scanPeriod` attribute `<configuration debug="true" scan="true" scanPeriod="1 minute">` it starts working:

```
16:43:44,584 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
16:43:44,585 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
16:43:44,585 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [file:/home/jbochenski/acme/acme-func-test/conf/logback.xml]
16:43:44,686 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - Will scan for changes in [file:/home/jbochenski/acme/acme-func-test/conf/logback.xml] 
16:43:44,686 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - Setting ReconfigureOnChangeTask scanning period to 1 minutes
16:43:44,688 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
16:43:44,691 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [CONSOLE]
16:43:44,700 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
16:43:44,727 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to WARN
16:43:44,727 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [CONSOLE] to Logger[ROOT]
16:43:44,727 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
16:43:44,728 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@f6c48ac - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
```

Using:

- `logback-classic`: 1.1.7
- `slf4j`: 1.7.13

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**UPDATE:** See [LOGBACK-1194](http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-1194)

---

This indeed looks like a logback bug, and I recommend filing an issue in [JIRA](http://jira.qos.ch/).

In 1.1.7, some [refactoring was done](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/commit/1518573) that affects how the `scanPeriod` is handled. The changes included [abandoning the `scan` option altogether when no `scanPeriod` is specified](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/commit/1518573#diff-f4a4959acd1d9ea90cf5915f2d67ccf0R110). I don't think that was intentional.

Comment: Done: http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-1194 
Can you please update your answer with the link for sake of completeness?

Comment: I'm using version 1.2.3 and it still seems broken, unfortunately.